# Задача на округление чисел в Java

Tags: java

Нужно написать метод, который получает на вход 4 дробных положительных числа, сумма которых является целым числом, а возвращает 4 целых числа с сохранением суммы. При этом числа могут быть любой точности.
Целые числа на выходе являются результатом округления дробных, а значит не должны отличаться от соответствующих входных чисел больше чем на 1 в ту или иную сторону.

Пример входных данных:

```
2,478
5,761
1,923
9,838
20
```

Пример выходных данных:

```
2
6
2
10
20
```

public class JavaApplication2 {

```
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */

public static void main(String[] args) {
    double i[] = { 2.5, 5.5, 1.003, 9.997};
    Index(i);
}
public static void Index(double[] a){
    int count = 0;
    System.out.println("Числа на входе:");
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
        System.out.println(a[i]);
    }
    //вычисляем сколько чисел с *.5
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
        if(a[i] - (int)a[i] == 0.5){
            count++;
        }
    }
    MathOp.SumAndRound(a, count);
}
public static class MathOp{
    public static void SumAndRound(double[] b, int cnt){
        ArrayList<Double> list = new ArrayList<>();
        double sumDouble = 0;
        int sumInt = 0;

        //вычислие суммы дробных
        for(int i = 0; i < b.length; i++){
            sumDouble += b[i];  
        } 
        //возвращает целое число, ближайшее к аргументу - стандартный метод
        if(cnt == 0){
            for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++){
                b[i] = Math.round(b[i]);
                list.add(b[i]);
            }  
        } 
        //если есть числа с *.5, то округляем в большую и в меньшую 
        // через одно число. Условие соблюдаем - числа не больше чем на 1 в ту или 
        //другую сторону
        else if(cnt > 0){
            //если дробное число *.0, то без округления
            for(int i = 0; i < b.length; i++){
                if(b[i] - (int)b[i] == 0.0){
                    list.add(b[i]);
                }
            }
            int count = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++){
                //если нет *.5 и число еще не округлено, то округляем его 
                // обычным способом
                if (b[i] - (int)b[i] != 0.5 && b[i] - (int)b[i] != 0.0){
                    b[i] = Math.round(b[i]);
                    list.add(b[i]);
                }
                if (b[i] - (int)b[i] == 0.5 && count == 0){
                    count++;
                    b[i] = Math.floor(b[i]);
                    list.add(b[i]); 
                }
                if(b[i] - (int)b[i] == 0.5 && count == 1){
                    count++;
                    b[i] = Math.ceil(b[i]);
                    list.add(b[i]);  
                }
                if (b[i] - (int)b[i] == 0.5 && count == 2){
                    count++;
                    b[i] = Math.floor(b[i]);
                    list.add(b[i]);
                }
                if (b[i] - (int)b[i] == 0.5 && count == 3){
                    count++;
                    b[i] = Math.ceil(b[i]);
                    list.add(b[i]);
                }
                if (b[i] - (int)b[i] == 0.5 && count == 4){
                    count++;
                    b[i] = Math.floor(b[i]);
                    list.add(b[i]);
                }
            }
        }
        double[] e = list.stream().mapToDouble(Double::doubleValue).toArray();

        System.out.println("Округлённые числа:");
        for(int i  = 0; i<e.length; i++){
            System.out.println(e[i]);
        }
        //сумма округлённых
        for(int i = 0; i < e.length; i++){
            sumInt += e[i];  
        }

        System.out.println("Сумма дробных: " + (int)sumDouble);
        System.out.println("Сумма округленных: " + sumInt);
        Equals((int)sumDouble,sumInt);
    }

    public static void Equals(int sumDouble, int sumInt){
       if(sumDouble == sumInt){
           System.out.println("Числа ровны");
       }
       else if(sumDouble < sumInt){
           System.out.println("Дробные меньше");
       }
       else if(sumDouble > sumInt){
           System.out.println("Дробные больше");
       }
       else System.out.println("Что-то пошло не так...");
    }
}
```

}

Проблема состоит в том, что если числа к примеру все с .9 (девять десятых), то суммы сильно разнятся.
Бьюсь часа 4 уже.

Может кто подскажет как доделать эту задачу?

Comment: Раз вам сумму надо сохранить, то, скорее всего, стандартные правила округления не получится применить (например, если все числа 0,25). Попробуйте просто перебор всех возможных 4-кортежей из элементов "округлить вверх" и "округлить вниз", с дополнителным условием, что сумма сохранится (всего 16 вариантов перебора, возможно, что правильных вариантов несколько)

Comment: Округляйте все вниз. Потом добавляйте по 1 вверх пока сумма не сойдется.

Comment: @pavel, Ваше решение было самым простым, спасибо! При чем сильно сократился код. Решено!